# How to delete accidental folder on /media

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, rsync

Earlier today, I made a home partition but accidentally labeled it "Home" instead of "home". And I was following [this tutorial on how to transfer files from the old home folder to the new partition.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)
However, I accidentally used this command:

```
sudo rsync -aXS --progress --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/home/.
```

Instead of this one:

```
sudo rsync -aXS --progress --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/Home/.
```

And now, I don't have space on the filesystem root partition and I have an undeleteable folder in /media (actually two from another mistake).
This is the error message:

```
rsync: write failed on "/media/home/oussema/Videos/Course": No space left on device (28)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(393) [receiver=3.1.2]
```

I can't make screenshots now to show the state of folders but I think it's clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these directories are the result of failed backup attempts, I assume that you have no data in them that you want to preserve, or that you've already saved the data elsewhere.

**NOTE be sure to type this command accurately - you can break your system with typos in this command.**

```
sudo rm -rf  /media/Home
```

This will delete the directory, and all the files and directories beneath it.

Comment: Actually, I need to delete the "/media/home" not "/media/Home".  I just found this command a minute ago and executed it with success. Thank you for writing an answer.  I will mark it as accepted after editing it.

Comment: nevermind, I'll just accept it